# How do I turn off vertex color?

Tags: 2d

I am working in 2D and following a tutorial by Dedouze. I am trying to fill in a box I drew with the color pink. When I fill it in the color comes out purple. I noticed whenever I change the vertex color (which displays in my header) the color I use to fill changes as well.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We would like to help, but what exactly is the problem? That the fill comes out purple or it changes with your vertex color? Please explain a little more clearly.